# Fastest way to learn Maven

Tags: java, maven

What is the fastest way to learn maven? I am up to speed with it but can't keep up with its idiosyncrasies. Any idea?

Comment: It would be better if you'd post an actual, concrete question about some feature of Maven that you don't understand. Your question above is far too vague, and we can't read your mind to understand what "idiosyncrasies" you don't understand.

Comment: See the following Books by Sonatype:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/pdf/mvnex-pdf.pdf
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/pdf/mvnref-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 17):

Start by looking [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/public-book.html).

Then, I would play with [archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/). They are quick ways of getting projects up and running. Even if you already have a project, playing with an archetype gives you a sense of what the conventions are and how things are layed out.

(If that link doesn't work, try the command mvn archetype:generate, and pick one of the archetypes from the list that seems closest to your real project.)

I also found that it just took a while for things to "click" since it is very different than ant or make.

Comment: your 2nd doesn't work, or is it just me ? Maybe http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetype+Plugin will help.

Comment: The best way to learn through the video tutorials here http://javabrains.koushik.org/2011/06/maven-tutorial-01-part-1-introduction.html